# How do I split text into columns, and then have separate columns for specific properties?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a column with text in the format below

| Properties |
| --- |
| admin_role=sales_other;;business_type=b2b;;categorisation_complete=yes;;company_reporting_segment_fy22=100+;;engage_usage=medium;;human_support_usage=high;;id=120518_1653500834_40618400058_cs;;job=support team collaboration;;lead_gen_usage=high;;primary_company_industry=software & technology;;problem=external collaboration;;product_area=apps & integrations;;source_link=https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/tx2p130c/inbox/inbox/all/conversations/40618400058;;subject=unclassified;;theme=slack integration;;type=feature request |
| business_type=b2c;;categorisation_complete=yes;;company_reporting_segment_fy22=500+;;engage_usage=medium;;human_support_usage=low;;id=001o000000yafi3aan_1653462492_ptbs;;job=omni-channel support;;lead_gen_usage=high;;primary_company_industry=software & technology;;problem=channel customization;;product_area=apps & integrations;;source_link=n/a;;subject=customization;;theme=channel |

I want to split this text with a column for each property. If I split by ';;', and because not all properties such as 'admin_role' apply to each row, I get something like the below:

| Properties |  |
| --- | --- |
| admin_role=sales_other | business_type=b2b |
| admin_role=other_other | business_type=other |
| business_type=b2c | categorisation_complete=yes |

What I would like is for it to be in the format below, so a column for 'admin_role', 'business_type', 'categorisation_complete, etc.

| Properties |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| admin_role=sales_other | business_type=b2b |  |
| admin_role=other_other | business_type=other |  |
|  | business_type=b2c | categorisation_complete=yes |

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I can't see how your example data is connected to desired output. Could you please explain a bit broader?

Comment: because not all properties such as 'admin_role' apply to each row, the columns have mixed values. What I'm trying to get is a column for each property - so a column for 'admin_role', 'business_type', 'categorisation_complete, etc.

Comment: Are you using Excel or Google Sheets? You have both tagged.

Comment: I'm using both - so I'd be happy to figure out how this works in either.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a solution in Excel. There may be fancier ways, but this definitely worked for me. The drawback that I see is that it relies upon you knowing what terms you're looking for instead of figuring it out for yourself. You could make a really complicated formula that figures it all out but, if it's not likely to change, you're probably better off putting in the manual labor to make that list yourself. First, I setup the sheet like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I listed the tags across the top and the raw text down the side. The screenshot shows the extraction of just the part after `=` but I'll show you how to pull the entire string, too. Let's break down that formula:

```
=IFERROR(LET(tag,B$1,text,$A2,start,FIND(tag,text)+LEN(tag)+1,end,FIND(";",text,start),MID(text,start,end-start)),"")
```

The `LET()` function allows you to define variables and then later reference them by name. The terms are in pairs of `variable, value` except the last term which is the output. Here are those terms:

- `tag,B$1` saves the tag we're looking for. Having it in one place instead of throughout the formula makes it easier to  update. Note that the column reference is relative `B` but the row is absolute `$1` so it'll update as you copy / paste across but not down.
- `text,$A2` saves the text we're searching within. Again, the references are such that it'll update as you copy / paste down but not across.
- `start,FIND(tag,text)+LEN(tag)+1` defines the start of the string we want to show in our result. It finds the tag inside the text and then adds the length of the tag plus one for the length of the equals sign. If you want the entire string instead, delete the `+LEN(tag)+1` from the end.
- `end,FIND(";",text,start)` defines the end of the string by finding the first semicolon after the start of the string.
- `MID(text,start,end-start)` extracts the string we want from the big input string.

Finally, we wrap the whole thing in `IFERROR(~,"")` so it returns blank if `tag` is not found within `text`.

Once this is setup, you copy / paste down as many rows as you have of data and across as many columns of tags you have.

---

If you have tons of rows and need help getting the list of tags, I would recommend this:

1. Paste all the data into a text editor
2. Find / replace every `;;` with a line break
3. Copy that data back into the spreadsheet
4. Use this function to extract everything before `=` (assuming the data starts in `A1`: `=LEFT(A1,FIND("=",A1)-1)`
5. Copy / paste that formula down the entire list
6. Copy / paste values of that column somewhere else then remove duplicates OR use a pivot table on that column to get a unique list OR use `=SORT(UNIQUE(B:B))` somewhere else.
7. Copy / paste *transposed* of that unique list into row 1 so you have all your column headers.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you so much. I'd never used the LET function before and definitely learnt something new today.